# Mongodb aggregation vs client side processing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a `blogs` collection which has almost the following schema:

```
{ 
    title: { name: "My First Blog Post",
             postDate: "01-28-11" },
    content: "Here is my super long post ...",
    comments: [ { text: "This post sucks!"
              , name: "seanhess"
              , created: 01-28-14}
            , { text: "I know! I wish it were longer"
              , name: "bob"
              , postDate: 01-28-11} 
            ] 
}
```

I mainly want to run three queries:

1. Give me all the `comments` made by **only** `bob`
2. Find all the `comments` made at the same day the post is written which is `comments.postDate = title.postDate`.
3. Find all the `comments` made by `bob` on the same day the post is written

My questions are as following:

- These three are going to be really frequent queries, so is it a good idea to use aggregation framework?
- For the third query, I can simply make a query like `db.blogs.find({"comments.name":"bob"}, {comments.name:1, comments.postDate:1, title.postDate:1})` and then do a client side post processing to loop through the returned results. Is it a good idea? I'd like to note that it is possible that this might return several thousand documents back.
- I will be happy if you can propose some ways to make the third query.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It probably is best practice here to "break-up" your **multiple** questions in to several questions, if not only for that maybe the answer on **one** question would have led you to understand the other.

I am also *not very keen* on answering anything where there is **no** example shown of what yo have tried to do. But with that said and "shooting myself in the foot", the questions are reasonable from a design approach so I will answer.

### Point 1 : Comments by "bob"

Standard $unwind and filter the results. Use $match first so you don't process unneeded documents.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Match to "narrow down" the documents.
    { "$match": { "comments.name": "bob" }},

    // Unwind the array
    { "$unwind": "$comments" },

    // Match and "filter" just the "bob" comments
    { "$match": { "comments.name": "bob" }},

    // Possibly wind back the array
    { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id",
       "title": { "$first": "$title" },
       "content": { "$first": "$content" },
       "comments": { "$push": "$comments" }
    }}
])
```

### Point 2: All comments on the same day

```js
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Try and match posts within a date or range
    // { "$match": { "title.postDate": Date( /* something */ ) }},

    // Unwind the array
    { "$unwind": "$comments" },

    // Aha! Project out the same day. Not the time-stamp.
    { "$project": {
        "title": 1,
        "content": 1,
        "comments": 1,
        "same": { "$eq": [
            {
                "year"   : { "$year":  "$title.postDate" },
                "month"  : { "$month": "$title.postDate" },
                "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$title.postDate" }
            },
            {
                "year"   : { "$year": "$comments.postDate" },
                "month"  : { "$month": "$comments.postDate" },
                "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$comments.postDate" }
            }
        ]}
     }},

     // Match the things on the "same 
     { "$match": { "same": true } },     

    // Possibly wind back the array
    { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id",
       "title": { "$first": "$title" },
       "content": { "$first": "$content" },
       "comments": { "$push": "$comments" }
    }}

])
```

### Point 3: "bob" on the same date

```js
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Try and match posts within a date or range
    // { "$match": { "title.postDate": Date( /* something */ ) }},

    // Unwind the array
    { "$unwind": "$comments" },

    // Aha! Project out the same day. Not the time-stamp.
    { "$project": {
        "title": 1,
        "content": 1,
        "comments": 1,
        "same": { "$eq": [
            {
                "year"   : { "$year":  "$title.postDate" },
                "month"  : { "$month": "$title.postDate" },
                "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$title.postDate" }
            },
            {
                "year"   : { "$year": "$comments.postDate" },
                "month"  : { "$month": "$comments.postDate" },
                "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$comments.postDate" }
            }
        ]}
     }},

     // Match the things on the "same" field
     { "$match": { "same": true, "comments.name": "bob" } },     

    // Possibly wind back the array
    { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id",
       "title": { "$first": "$title" },
       "content": { "$first": "$content" },
       "comments": { "$push": "$comments" }
    }}

])
```

### Results

Honestly, and especially if you are using some *indexing* to feed to the initial $match stages of these operations, then it should be very clear that this will "run rings" around trying to iterate this in code.

At the **very least** this reduces the returned records *"over the wire"*, so there is less network traffic. And of course there is less (or *nothing*) to **post process** once the query results have been received.

As a general convention, database server hardware tends to be an *order of magnitude* higher rated in performance than *"application server"* hardware. So again the general condition is that anything executed on the **server** will run faster.

- **Is aggregation the right thing**: "Yes". and by a long long way. You even get a *cursor* very soon.
- **How can you do the queries you want**: Shown to be pretty simple. And in real world code we never "hard code" this, we build it *dynamically*. So adding conditions and attributes should be as simple as all you normal *data manipulation* code.

So I **would not normally** answer this *style* of question. But say thank-you! Please ?

Comment: Thanks Neil, great answer. Sorry for putting all queries at once, but what I wanted is just to show the type of queries I am going to be doing. The main reason of this question is *client side processing vs aggregation* which you have clarified nicely.